# Generic composable component props for interface

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

I'm working on a functional component that composes other components that are passed in. My interface looks like this:

```
interface IMyComponentProps {
  ...
  /** What custom component to use */
  elem?: React.ReactNode;
  /** Custom component props */
  elemProps?: any;
}
```

I'm wondering if there is a way I can make this a generic instead of using `any` for the `elemProps` propery. Is there a way to get the props of whatever `elem` happens to be?

Comment: How do intend this to be used? Because `ReactNode` is the type of already rendered JSX, which means that you wouldn't need any props at all.

Comment: I'm composing it: `const MyElem: any = props.elem;` ... `<ColElem {...props.elemProps} />`

Answer (score 1):

I thin this is what you want:

```
interface IMyComponentProps<T extends React.ComponentType<any>> {
  /** What custom component to use */
  elem: T;
  /** Custom component props */
  elemProps: React.ComponentProps<T>;
}
```

`ReactComponent<Props>` is the type of a component that you would pass props to to render. And `ComponentProps<T>` is the type that returns the props from a `ReactComponent`.

Testing this, it seems to works like you expect:

```
function Wrapper<T extends React.ComponentType<any>>({elem, elemProps}: IMyComponentProps<T>) {
    const Elem = elem
    return <Elem {...elemProps} />
}

function Test(props: { a: number, b: string }) {
    return <></>
}

// works
const testWrapper = <Wrapper elem={Test} elemProps={{ a: 1, b: 'hello' }} />

// error as expected
const testWrapperError = <Wrapper elem={Test} elemProps={{ a: 1, c: 'hello' }} />
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=22&ssc=82&pln=9&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIFkCeBhA9gWwAdcQJwAFKXQgZwB4AVZCAD0hABMbkAlCRMADo8REmTANMhCHTghMAPgXIA3gChkyAPQAqHcgDqACzhhkCAK40wBcwWKlwyG8isodWjcwA2EfAC5kBgBuL119bCsbfDtRRzNCKlpkDy8IX3xKahpAvgFhezEKJPoGBVCAXzVqmAsQBDBgEkMoOEJpKEZmNjIuXn4GgrjxSWlZeSUAChV0vwAaHz8s2grAjBxC+OXShQBKVS9NBBJrZABRDOQAXkX8Q+QoCDALKBBkOgu-VUEf2cySiraBRqKpqWr1RrNBgQayTRLZQIqZBwQIgCz4ABG0AWGMC1igoAA5sgKvt1JpNI9nq93go6FpgaCtFpkAB3XBQADWNDUxxAp0g1gMrXa0Gu72FbQ6tyuKmh1kBf22sqRKOQAEYcYEAORGdLeXDakmAhnVZnMKBUKDI7isaQNCAcXknMyCsCS0VQM6Wjniuge6V-WXysCKjLKlSqwKa8w6vXeA1GiomhRAA)

Comment: So I'm running into an issue doing it like this... The component that is using it takes an array of these as a prop, and so I need a generic way of allowing it to be used. Relevant part of the interface: `elems?: IMyComponentProps<any>[];`. When I go to use it, both `elem` and `elemProps` show as `any`

Comment: You mean [like this?](https://tsplay.dev/WP7nqm) If not, then you'll need to post a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that is showing your type errors from your intended usage.

Comment: Okay, so I updated your example and it just grabs the type from the first item in the array passed in: [Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mpgVgN)